# Find first vowel in word - bash

Tags: bash, shell

I've found a couple of other answers for this question using regular programming languages but not one for bash. I'm trying to write a bash script and I've run into the problem of being able to locate the first vowel in a given string. My goal is to see if a word begins with one or more consonants and then move those consonants to the end of the word and add "ay" and then print out the word. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `[^aeiou]*` .... ?

Comment: @Roadowl Yeh I was thinking that, the only thing is I need to save the consonant so I can then print it out at the end of the word

Comment: And of course after writing that answer (below) I did a google search on `bash pig latin generator` and received a bunch of hits on SO and SE; so don't be surprised if someone flags and closes this question as a duplicate ...

Answer (score 2):

One idea using `sed` and regex/capture groups:

```
$ sed -E 's/(^[^aeiouAEIOU]*)(.*)/\2\1ay/g' <<< 'nix'
ixnay
$ sed -E 's/(^[^aeiouAEIOU]*)(.*)/\2\1ay/g' <<< 'NIX'
IXNay
$ sed -E 's/(^[^aeiouAEIOU]*)(.*)/\2\1ay/g' <<< 'potato'
otatopay
$ sed -E 's/(^[^aeiouAEIOU]*)(.*)/\2\1ay/g' <<< 'school'
oolschay
```

Where:

- `sed -E` - run in extended regex mode
- `(^[^aeiouAEIOU]*)` - first capture group starts at the beginning of the input (first `^`) and includes everything up to the first vowel (ie, everything that is not in `aeiouAEIOU`)
- `(.*)` - second capture group grabs the rest of the input (ie, from the first vowel to the end of the input)
- `\2\1ay` - output 2nd capture group (`\2`), then the 1st capture group (`\1`), then `'ay`'
- `<<< 'nix'` - a 'here string' that allows us to feed a string as stdin to the `sed` command